# Query to count the number of tables I have in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am growing the number of tables I have and I am sometimes curious just to do a quick command line query to count the number of tables in my database.  Is that possible?  If so, what is the query?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName';
```

[Source](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-150957.html)

This is mine:

```
USE databasename; 
SHOW TABLES; 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: I've tried the above 2 methods and the number of tables which returned when I used `FOUND_ROWS()` was greater than the number of tables which returned when I used the first method.

Comment: this also count views, if you only want tables, add `AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'`

Comment: Just a note about the `use databasename;` command. If the database is really big, the command can execute with a long wait time. In that case, login should be done with the option -A, ie: `mysql -uroot -p -A`, and the command will work fast.

Answer (score 25):

In case you would like a count all the databases plus a summary, please try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(table_schema,'Total') "Database",TableCount 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) TableCount,table_schema 
      FROM information_schema.tables 
      WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') 
      GROUP BY table_schema WITH ROLLUP) A;
```

Here is a sample run:

```
mysql> SELECT IFNULL(table_schema,'Total') "Database",TableCount
    -> FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) TableCount,table_schema
    ->       FROM information_schema.tables
    ->       WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')
    ->       GROUP BY table_schema WITH ROLLUP) A;
+--------------------+------------+
| Database           | TableCount |
+--------------------+------------+
| performance_schema |         17 |
| Total              |         17 |
+--------------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.29 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I only got it working when I used only the subquery. There was a syntax error if I tried to run the entire query/subquery.

Comment: @Gaia Sorry, I forgot that Database was a reserved word. So, I surrounded the word with Double Quotes.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA This is sweet, do you have one to also show the total  db size of all db's as well?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Try my DBA.SE post : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/translating-backup-size-to-database-size/31804#31804

Comment: Why the subquery in the `FROM` clause?  Why not just `SELECT IFNULL(table_schema, 'Total') Database, COUNT(*) TableCount FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql') GROUP BY table_schema WITH ROLLUP`?

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to get the count of tables without views you can do it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbo' and TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 7):

This will give you names and table count of all the databases in you mysql

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables group by TABLE_SCHEMA;
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple ways to count the tables of a database. My favorite is this on:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    `information_schema`.`tables`
WHERE
    `table_schema` = 'my_database_name'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

from command line :

```
mysql -uroot -proot  -e "select count(*) from 
information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'database_name';"
```

in above example root is username and password , hosted on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

> mysql> show tables;

it will show the names of the tables, then the count on tables.

[source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-count-the-number-of-tables-in-a-mysql-database)