# How to count no. of existing tables in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I am sometimes curious just to do a quick command line query to count the number of tables in my database. Is that possible in MySQL? If so, what is the query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query to count the number of tables I have in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201012/query-to-count-the-number-of-tables-i-have-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this SQL query:

```
USE <database_name>; 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.tables;
```

In the command above, replace the  placeholder with the actual database name.