# Number of Tables in Database

Tags: sql, rdbms

> How to count number of tables in a database ?

```
SELECT COUNT *    
FROM SHOW TABLES AS A
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MySql with Wampserver thnx for asking ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName';
```

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: nearly all. It doesn't work for Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'dbName';
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201012/query-to-count-the-number-of-tables-i-have-in-mysql)

This one is easy

```
USE databasename; SHOW TABLES; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: For which DBMS is the second statement?

Comment: Well this one is for My Sql by adding same logic it might work for other.

Comment: I don't see how the second one could ever work for Oracle, Postgres, Firebird or DB2 (just to name a few)

Comment: I have checked with MySql need to check with others.

Comment: I wouldn't bother until tanay final tells us which DBMS he/she is using.