# How can we list empty databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried looking out on web about how we can list out the empty databases in MySQL but couldn't find any solution it. I know we can do it for the tables but is it possible to do it for the databases as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to count the number of tables I have in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201012/query-to-count-the-number-of-tables-i-have-in-mysql)

Comment: This answer specifically seems to work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201910/1790644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like databases that contain no tables?

```
mysql> show tables from test;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT S.SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T ON S.SCHEMA_NAME = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE T.TABLE_SCHEMA IS NULL;
+-------------+
| SCHEMA_NAME |
+-------------+
| test        |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But if I want to delete these databases that have no tables... Can you please explain to me how can I do it with SQL?

Comment: For each empty database identified by the above query, you can run `DROP DATABASE <schema_name>`. In other words, you would write application code to loop over the result of the query and execute one DROP DATABASE statement for each one.

Comment: Thanks again! But can't we do it with stored procedures may be?

Comment: I almost never recommend using stored procedure in MySQL.

Comment: It take too many time on many databases;

Answer (score 0):

just use 
`show databases;`
will show all databases even there is no table in that database.