# How to find out the number of tables in a SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have a database `db` with multiple tables `t1,t2 and t3`.
How do I find out the number of tables in one specific database without having to count it manually.

Also, is it possible to find out the number of rows in each table as well in the same query?

Comment: `number of tables in one specific table` <- this makes my head hurt. Tables don't contain other tables.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? You have 3 tagged.

Comment: You can find both using product-specific queries. You can't write one query that will work across all 3 products

Comment: Query this data from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query to count the number of tables I have in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201012/query-to-count-the-number-of-tables-i-have-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT [schema]       = s.name, 
       [table]        = t.name, 
       NumberOfRows   = SUM(p.rows), 
       NumberOfTables = COUNT(*) OVER()
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
    ON t.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
  WHERE p.index_id IN (0,1)
  GROUP BY s.name, t.name
  ORDER BY s.name, t.name;
```

And to run this against any arbitrary database:

```
DECLARE @db sysname = N'db';

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(800),
        @sql  nvarchar(max) = N'
  SELECT [schema]       = s.name, 
         [table]        = t.name, 
         NumberOfRows   = SUM(p.rows), 
         NumberOfTables = COUNT(*) OVER()
    FROM sys.schemas AS s
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
      ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
      ON t.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
    WHERE p.index_id IN (0,1)
    GROUP BY s.name, t.name
    ORDER BY s.name, t.name;';

SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql ';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```

For MySQL and MariaDB you're going to have to ask another question because no query will work in all three products.

Comment: So sorry, Idk what went through my head while I was typing.
I meant multiple databases and how to get the number of tables in one db.